# Technet vs MSDN O/S Subscription

Tags: licensing, msdn, microsoft-technet

Can anyone please explain the differences between a Technet and 'MSDN O/S Subscription' ?

I have customers who use a range of different Microsoft operating systems and I want to be able to spin a VM up using the relevant OS to replicate their environment. I would then want to run s/w which has been developed by me to ensure it works as it should in their enviroment.

Assume for the moment that I'm not interested in any access to support calls, email support, etc which might be bundled with either product.

Assume also that I'm only interested in English language versions of the operating systems (I've read somewhere that MSDN gives you more language versions of the OS's but that's not of interest to me).

Is there some reason I should not purchase the Technet subscription at approximately 1/3rd the cost ?

(BTW I did ask MS this on the phone but the person I was talking couldn't explain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technet = Software for evaluation

MSDN = Software for development

If you're a developer you must by the MSDN subscription if you need to develop application for different Windows versions.

If your customer needs to test software under different Windows versions, the Technet subscription is right for him.